# Yii CGridView Filter

Tags: php, filter, yii

I want CGridView's filter to work with multiple words in one column at the time. For example i want to show all rows with "A" in first column plus all the rows with "B" in the same column.

Does anybody know which class and function should i override to do this?

Answer (score 4):

You will have to modify the search() function in your model. The search() function will have something like this -

```
    $criteria->compare('your_column_name', $this->your_column_name, true);
```

you can modify it by breaking the input, which is in $this->your_column_name and adding one compare condition for each of the elements in the input. You can use explode() to break the string into multiple terms.

Comment: thanks, works great, also i needed to fill in the operator parameter of compare method as 'OR'

Comment: compare function accepts 5 parameters, 3 of which are optional. The forth parameter specifies the operator. in your case you can use
$criteria->compare('your_column_name', $this->your_column_name, true, 'OR')
Checkout the api documentation for more details - http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#compare-detail